# VideoView not playing video from URL

Tags: android, android-videoview

I've tried everything I found regarding VideoView, but I still only get a blank black container, without any error message in the console or on the device.

I tried it with SGS3 and Xperia U, neither worked.

Here's the code for the activity's oncreate function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
//      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String videoPath = "http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp";
        String videoPath2 = "http://www.law.duke.edu/cspd/contest/finalists/viewentry.php?file=docandyou";
        VideoView aboutVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.aboutVideoView);

        aboutVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath2));
        aboutVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        aboutVideoView.setVisibility(1);
        aboutVideoView.bringToFront();
        aboutVideoView.requestFocus();
        aboutVideoView.start(); 
    }
```

I tried commenting/uncommenting different lines, tried both videos sources, but I couldn't make it play. I'm hoping someone will find what's wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: see the solution I have posted. I am able to play both videopaths with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works well.

Just check for the Internet Permission in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the permission is set as well. The app uses layar sdk, which requires internet to run (and it works). Weird...

Comment: @MarianoGrandioso seems it works well for me. you can give a try with the video from the sdcard too.